# How to read first N of values from Postgres array

Tags: postgresql

I have `ARRAY_AGG( distinct CAST (asset_group_id AS text))` which returns array of hundreds of elements but I want only first 100 elements.

I didn't find any such function available in postgres array [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html).

How can I achieve it in the postgres?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PostgreSQL arrays support [subscripts and slices](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html#ARRAYS-ACCESSING).
In your case, to get the first 100 elements: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/90qh87BP)

```sql
(ARRAY_AGG( distinct asset_group_id::text) )[:100]
```

> It is possible to omit the lower-bound and/or upper-bound of a slice specifier; the missing bound is replaced by the lower or upper limit of the array's subscripts.

It's better for static, existing arrays. In your case, you're building one, collecting all your distinct elements and this discards everything past that first 100, wasting the rest of the work put into finding all other distinct values. It's better to *not* collect more than you need in the first place, as [Pepe N O suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77009198/5298879), using a [`limit`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-limit.html) in a [CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html):

```sql
with cte as (select distinct asset_group_id::text 
             from tests 
             limit 100)
select ARRAY_AGG(asset_group_id) 
from cte;
```

or a plain [subquery](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-SUBQUERIES)

```sql
select ARRAY_AGG(asset_group_id) 
from (select distinct asset_group_id::text 
      from tests 
      limit 100) as subquery;
```

The [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/90qh87BP) shows the performance difference between just grabbing the first distinct 100 and no more, versus having to collect all distincts and then discarding everything past the first 100.

Comment: Second full paragraph is sage advice only taught by experience.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a CTE to limit to 100 elements, then create the array, like

```
with elements as(
select distinct cast(asset_group_id as text) id 
from my_table limit 100)
select array_agg(id) from elements;
```

Comment: Your second example is not valid: see [this demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/nYFN7BZJ). [`DISTINCT`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-select-lists.html#QUERIES-DISTINCT) applies to entire rows of the `SELECT`, all of the columns that follow it - not just the first one - so adding the row_number made all entries distinct by nature, even if they are all duplicates. It's faster because this lets it fetch the actual first 100 values, not the first 100 *distinct* values. Still, I support the idea of only collecting the 100 you're after.

Comment: @Zegarek you're right, deleting that.